# Python 3 printing list without square brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print a list without brackets.

my code is:

```
import math
bignumber = int(input("Enter a value: "))
listofsquares = []
for counter in range(bignumber):
    squareroot = math.sqrt(counter)
    if squareroot.is_integer():
        square = squareroot*squareroot
        listofsquares.append(int(square))
" ".join(str(listofsquares))
print(listofsquares)
```

My output is:

```
Enter a value: 100
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

I was expecting the .join() to get rid of the brackets, however it only gets rid of the quotations. Which is especially odd because it has removed them when using this before.

Comment: You really need to put your code and output in your question itself. Images of code make it impossible for anyone to copy and paste your code so that they can run it. Also, the reason it does that is because you're not joining a list, you're joining a string.

Comment: I tried but the format was all messed up. It wouldn't accept new lines or indents. I will edit it in though.

Comment: Highlight the code and hit Ctrl + K.

Comment: `" ".join(str(listofsquares))`. You're not join `listofsquares`. You're joining `listofsquares` after converting it to a string. So it takes each character of the string representation of `listofsquares` and joins it with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling `str(listofsquares)`, which will return a string representing the listofsquares list, namely `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]` in your example. Also, in this case `" ".join(str(listofsquares))` is joining a list of the characters which compose the string above with the space separator, which will result in the string `[ 0 ,   1 ,   4 ,   9 ,   1 6 ,   2 5 ,   3 6 ,   4 9 ,   6 4 ,   8 1 ]`.

I guess what you were trying to achieve is printing a string with the numbers divided by spaces, which you achieve by list comprehension:

```
" ".join([str(num) for num in listofsquares])
```

Comment: why create another list, when you could just append str values in the first place? seems like more work than needed

Comment: That's another valid option.

Comment: Or just `" ".join(str(num) for num in listofsquares)`

Comment: It's **not** joining a list of just one element. It's joining the string's elements. You overlooked the main problem.

Comment: You're still overlooking the main problem. Changing their join to yours won't affect the output at all.